# Can I Delay a NetSuite Workflow By 5 Minutes?

Tags: workflow, netsuite, delay

We're using Solar Success with NetSuite. I have one workflow that creates a Customer record, which then triggers the creation of a Project record. I have another workflow that looks for existing Project records, then create a series of folder in GDrive.

The problem is that the search used by the GDrive workflow will sometimes see that the Project exists before the Project has fully populated all of its fields. When this happens, the GDrive workflow throws this error and sends me an email:

> Errors on Records:
> Internal ID : 12345 - Record has been changed

It then waits another 30 minutes before trying again.

If I could delay the execution of the GDrive workflow by 5 minutes, that would solve the problem and I wouldn't get 10+ error emails every day.

There isn't a 'sleep' state, so I checked into Transitions, but the minimum delay is 1 hour. I can't find any other way to pause a workflow.

Is there a way – native or not – that I can make a workflow pause for 5 minutes? Maybe by modifying the search?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the wait-for workflow transition?
Click on a transition between 2 state > Select the desired workflow
[image]